# R S3 system - generic groups

Tags: r

I'm testing a method for generic group functions, and there's an anomaly that I don't understand why. Note the code below.

## R code:

```
min.ben <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) print("Test")

x <- structure(2:5, class = "ben")

min(x)
```

## output:

```
[1] "Test"

[1] "Test"
```

## Question and doubt

Why does this double exit occur? I suspect that because the print function is also generic, some anomaly may be occurring. The idea is not to replace the print function with a non-generic function or any other alternative, but you know why that happens!

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function returns its argument, but normally does it invisibly.  So the result of your `min(x)` will be `"Test"`, but somehow the invisibility marker got lost.  That looks like a bug to me.

You can see this by using `withVisible()`:

```
> withVisible(min(x))
[1] "Test"
$value
[1] "Test"

$visible
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: There is no bug. OP is basically doing `x <- print("Test"); x`. Except for debugging and in `print` methods, `print` (or its methods) shouldn't be used within a function.

Comment: @Roland, you should try `min.ben(x)`.  You'll get the expected result, because the invisibility is kept.  There's no `; x` in the code, it just acts as though there is when the generic is called.  Or replace `print(x)` with `invisible(x)`, and you still get a visible result.  That's a bug.

Comment: I see. However, I'm not sure there is any contract in the documentation that the invisibility marker is preserved in this case. OP's issue seems to only exist if the generic is a `.Primitive` and method dispatch doesn't happen with `UseMethod`. A `min` method having an invisible return value was likely not anticipated by R Core.

Comment: @Roland exactly, the problem only occurs with primitive functions. When I create a generic, it doesn't happen with the print function. See the code below:        `fgenerica <- function(x) UseMethod("fgenerica")`;
`fgenerica.ben <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) print("Test")`;
`x <- structure(2:5, class = "ben")`;
`fgenerica(x)`

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that as object x has a 'ben' class, the print function is a generic function too, and I notice the fact that there is no print.ben method, the generic one dispatches in print.default, which causes this error. In my view, this could be an anomaly, that is, a bug.

Comment: I don't think `print(x)` is ever called in your code, so the generic would never try to dispatch on an object of class `"ben"`.  Or are you talking about some different code?

Answer (score 0):

@user2554330, I preferred to show that the problem may be the dispatch in `print.default()`. See for this code below, I will create a `print.ben()` method and the error will not occur as informed in the initial question. To make it clearer I just created an x ​​argument to the `min.ben()` method. See:

```
min.ben <- function(x, ..., na.rm = FALSE) {
  print(x) 
}

print.ben <- function(x) {
  "Dispatched in print.ben"
}

x <- structure(2:5, class = "ben")
min(x)
## [1] "Dispatched in print.ben"
```

If you remove `print.ben()`, the same error occurs, ie the double result. The only explanation I see is the output of print.default.

Comment: Your `print` method is not actually a proper `print` method because it doesn't print.